# Palavra chave no domínio ou diretório?

Tags: seo

Andei lendo sobre SEO e bateu a dúvida.
Hoje em dia ter um domínio com alguma palavra chave vale a pena ou basta adicionar essa palavra em algum diretório?

Exemplo de palavra chave: Camisa Polo

O site ficaria melhor se fosse:

**camisapolo**.com

ou

nomedosite.com/**camisa-polo**

Caso o google não indexe o nome do site por causa que não contem a palavra chave no domínio vale a pena fazer um redirect para nomedosite.com/camisa-polo como padrão ao inves de nomedosite.com?

E a última dúvida é verdade que palavra chave no domínio é considerado black hat?

Comment: As palavras chaves podem ser inseridas em uma meta tag no `head` do site ou com schemas no `body` do site. ex: <meta name="keywords" content=" camisa polo"> .

Comment: Então, mas mesmo com isso o site não aparece bem colocado nas buscas. Estou tentando fazer de tudo para ter um site de acordo com o que os buscadores indexam melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael,

O uso da palavra chave no nome do domínio não é considerado Black Hat. A questão é que antigamente este era um fator de ranqueamento que dava bastante retorno e o Google acabou mudando o algoritimo.

É uma boa prática ter a palavra-chave na URL ou ao domínio.

Se tiver alguma dúvida sobre quais são as práticas Black Hat, [veja este artigo](http://larahvidotti.com.br/black-hat-e-white-hat-seo/).

De acordo com o seu exemplo, Camisa Polo é o nome da marca ou é um dos produtos que o site irá conter?

Caso seja um dos produtos, sugiro seguir:

nomedosite.com/camisa-polo

Assim como poderá fazer com os outros produtos.

Também sugiro que utilize a ferramenta do Google > Google WebMasters Tool para verificar e acompanhar a indexação do site. Você consegue também identificar se há algum erro que precisa ser corrigido.

Espero ter ajudado!